# Could not find gradle wrapper

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework

> ionic-hello-world@0.0.0 ionic:build C:\Users\Cast\Desktop\HTML5\todo
>
> ionic-app-scripts build

[09:29:00]  ionic-app-scripts 1.3.6

[09:29:00]  build dev started ...

[09:29:01]  clean started ...

[09:29:01]  clean finished in 169 ms

[09:29:01]  copy started ...

[09:29:01]  transpile started ...

[09:29:37]  transpile finished in 36.65 s

[09:29:37]  preprocess started ...

[09:29:38]  deeplinks started ...

[09:29:38]  deeplinks finished in 21 ms

[09:29:38]  preprocess finished in 137 ms

[09:29:38]  webpack started ...

[09:29:41]  copy finished in 40.72 s

[09:29:59]  webpack finished in 21.84 s

[09:29:59]  sass started ...

[09:30:03]  sass finished in 3.46 s

[09:30:03]  postprocess started ...

[09:30:03]  postprocess finished in 53 ms

[09:30:03]  lint started ...

[09:30:03]  build dev finished in 62.61 s

[09:30:09]  lint finished in 6.29 s

ANDROID_HOME=D:\Software\adt-bundle-windows-x86\SDK\

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101

Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.

windows-x86\SDK\tools\templates\gradle\wrapper

I already install most all in the android SDK...

[image][image][image]
[image]

Comment: ionic build android give me an error but when i try to run it on android studio it work.. with no problem.. everything is up to date.. i dont know the problem but maybe ionic has a problem? nevertheless i will just use android studio to build for android and to test....

Answer (score 0):

Go to the sdk tool in android studio and see what needs to be updated. Update everything. Also, the main problem isn't with the sdk. It is with your gradle. Update your gradle as well. Then restart Android Studio and see if anything changes.

Comment: I already did the update... everything is uptodate... but the command ionic build android... give an error... i try to run it on android studio and it works find... with no problem...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For someone else looking the solution, this helped for me:

```
npm install -g cordova
cd <project_dir>
cordova platform update android
```